# Error code 0x8007045d when trying to install Windows 8

Tags: windows-8.1, windows-installation

My son's laptop was failing for the second time, so he decided to erase the hard drive and try to install Windows 8.1 back onto it, but it doesn't install. My error message (as shown in the photo) is:

```
We couldn't install Windows in the location you chose.  
Please check your media drive. Here's more info about what happened: 0x8007045d.
```

[image]

Comment: What is your question?  Please update your question to include all relevant information required to help you.

Comment: That error is generally associated with a problem with your HDD. Having said that, with regard to the body of your question, Huh?

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking here. It sounds like you have a failing disk, but we need *far* more information than that. I'm FTC'ing as unclear.

Comment: my sons laptop was failing for the second time, so he decided to erase the hard drive and try to install windows 8.1 back onto it but it doesn't install giving error code 0x8007045D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

0x8007045D = ERROR_IO_DEVICE (The request could not be performed because of an I/O device error).

That error indicates a problem with the HDD.

---

### Beware: Everything below this line will erase your disk.

---

Boot from the install media and instead of install, select "repair your computer" option. Select the command prompt at the x sources prompt type:-

`DISKPART`

`LIST DISK`

`SELECT DISK 0` (Where Disk 0 is the internal HDD)

`CLEAN`

`CREATE PARTITION PRIMARY`

`FORMAT FS=NTFS LABEL="Local Disk"`

`ACTIVE`

`EXIT`

Restart computer with install media, and this time select install.

Comment: cheers greetings and salutations

Comment: thank you TD.512 but it stuck on 4%, i'm guessing its goosed

Comment: yeah. still, if the answer helped, mind marking it as the answer?

Comment: is there any other way to repair the hard drive ?